# Create a numeric vector from 1 to n each time, given a vector of ns

Tags: r, vector, numeric

It sounds confusing from the title, but it should be very clear with the following examples.

Say I have the following vector `a`:

```
a=c(3,10,6,7)
```

I want a vector `b`, so that it covers from 1 to each of the numbers in `a` each time, resulting in:

```
b=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

To complete the task, if a number in `a` is ==1, I don't want that 1 alone, but rather an `NA`. In this case, if `a` is:

```
a=c(3,10,6,1,7)
```

`b` should be:

```
b=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

How should I do that easily with base tools? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `sequence(a)` should be preferred here over, e.g., `unlist(lapply(a, seq_len))`. And once you work out where the length-1 subsequences begin, you can subassign `NA`:

```r
a <- c(3, 10, 6, 1, 7)
replace(sequence(a), cumsum(a)[a == 1], NA)
##  [1]  1  2  3  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
## [11]  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA
## [21]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```